# A queue in my producer-consumer app is indicated as empty, after the queue is added to. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My program is split up into two types of threads: producer, and consumer. The "producer" threads model the production of cars, while the "consumer" threads model the selling of the cars. The idea is for a consumer thread to sell a car as soon as the car is produced, so I'm using a binary semaphore for the consumer thread(s) to wait for a car to be produced, as signalled by each "producer" thread.

Here is my code:

**cars.h**

```
/***********************************************************************
 * Component
 *    Cars
 * Summary:
 *    This will deal with the details of working with cars
 *
 *    Note that you must compile this with the -lpthread switch:
 *        g++ -lpthread lab06.cpp
 ************************************************************************/

#ifndef CARS_H
#define CARS_H

#include <iostream>      // for COUT
#include <queue>         // for QUEUE
#include <cassert>       // for ASSERT


/*************************************************
 * CAR
 * A car in the inventory consists of a model and a serial number
 ************************************************/
struct Car
{
   const char * model;
   int serialNumber;
};

/******************************************
 * DISPLAY CAR
 * Display one car in a user-friendly way
 ****************************************/
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Car & car)
{
   out << car.model << "(#" << car.serialNumber << ")";
   return out;
}

// the number of cars in the production run across all models
#define NUM_CARS 50

// The major models are the following
const char * models[4] =
{
   "540",
   "570GT",
   "650S Spider",
   "P1"
};
inline int numModels() { return sizeof(models) / sizeof(models[0]); }

// A sampling of the retailers are the following
const char * retailers[9] =
{
   "McLaren Beverly Hills",
   "McLaren Monaco",
   "McLaren Palm Beach",
   "McLaren Philadelphia",
   "McLaren Atlanta",
   "McLaren Rancho Mirage",
   "McLaren Tampa Bay",
   "McLaren Paris",
   "McLaren Birmingham"
};
inline int numRetailers() { return sizeof(retailers) / sizeof(retailers[0]); }

/*************************************************************
 * INVENTORY
 * The cars currently in inventory.
 * This class is _NOT_ thread-safe and should not be made so
 ************************************************************/
class Inventory
{
public:
   // default constructor: no cars
   Inventory() : maxCars(0) {}

   // how many cars were in there?
   int getMax() const { return maxCars; }

   // is the inventory empty?
   bool empty() const { return cars.size() == 0 ? true : false; }

   // add a car
   void makeCar(const Car & car)
   {
      cars.push(car);
      maxCars = (cars.size() > maxCars ? cars.size() : maxCars);
   }

   // sell a car
   Car sellCar()
   {
      assert(cars.size() > 0);
      Car car = cars.front();
      cars.pop();
      return car;
   }

private:
   int  maxCars;              // the biggest the inventory has yet been
   std::queue <Car> cars;     // the actual cars in the inventory
};

#endif // CARS_H
```

**The lab**

```
#include <iostream>      // for COUT
#include <cassert>       // for ASSERT
#include <string>        // for STRING
#include <sstream>       // for STRINGSTREAM
#include <queue>         // for QUEUE
#include <ctime>         // for time(), part of the random process
#include <unistd.h>      // for usleep()
#include <stdlib.h>      // for rand() and srand()
#include "cars.h"        // for everything dealing with McLaren Cars
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;
// Mutex locks
pthread_mutex_t serialNumberLock;
pthread_mutex_t inventoryLock;
// Semaphore
sem_t semaphore;
// This variable represents the shared memory between the parent thread
// and all the children. Recall from the reading how the main way for
// threads to communicate is through shared memory. This shared memory
// needs to be global.
bool productionComplete = false;
/***********************************************
 * PRoDUCER_ARGS
 * This stores arguments for the "producer" function.
 ***********************************************/
struct ProducerArgs
{
   const char *model;
   int producerNumber=0;
   Inventory *inventory;
   int beginningSerialNumber=0;
   int endingSerialNumber=0;
};
/***********************************************
 * CONSUMER_ARGS
 * This stores arguments for the "consumer" function.
 ***********************************************/
struct ConsumerArgs
{
   const char* retailer;
   Inventory *inventory;
};

void   *  producer(void *args);   // you may need to change this
void * consumer(void *args);   // you may need to change this also

int getNumber(const char * prompt, int max);



/***********************************************
 * MAIN
 * This will serve to prompt the user for the number
 * of models and the number of retailers. It will then
 * begin the simulation
 ***********************************************/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // Initialize the semaphore.
   sem_init(&semaphore,0,1);
   // set up the random number generator
   srand(argc == 1 ? time(NULL) : (int)argv[1][1]);
   // determine how many producer and consumer threads
   int numProducer = getNumber("How many models?    ", numModels());
   int numConsumer = getNumber("How many retailers? ", numRetailers());   
   // produce the cars. Note that this code needs to change. We will
   // need to launch one thread per producer here
   // Consumer threads should fire as soon as a producer produces a car.
   Inventory inventory;
   pthread_t *producerThreads = new pthread_t[numProducer];
   // Divide the work among the threads.
   int numCars[4];
   int numCarsPerProducer = NUM_CARS / numProducer;
   int remainderCarsPerProducer = NUM_CARS % numProducer;
   for (int i=0; i < numProducer; i++)
      numCars[i] = numCarsPerProducer;
   if (remainderCarsPerProducer > 0)
      numCars[0] += remainderCarsPerProducer;
   int beginningSerialNumber=1;
   int endingSerialNumber=0;
   ProducerArgs *producerArgs = new ProducerArgs[numProducer];
   for (int i = 0; i < numProducer; i++)
   {  
      ProducerArgs *pArgs = &(producerArgs[i]);
      pArgs->model = models[i];
      pArgs->inventory = &inventory;
      pArgs->producerNumber = i;
      pArgs->beginningSerialNumber = beginningSerialNumber;
      endingSerialNumber += numCars[i];
      pArgs->endingSerialNumber = endingSerialNumber;
      assert(pArgs->endingSerialNumber <= numProducer * NUM_CARS);
      assert(pthread_create(
                           &(producerThreads[i]),
                           NULL,
                           producer,
                           pArgs
                           ) == 0);
      beginningSerialNumber = endingSerialNumber + 1;
   }
   assert(endingSerialNumber == 50);
   // sell the cars. Note that this code also needs to change.
   cout << "\nThe cars sold from the various retailers:\n\n";
   ConsumerArgs *consumerArgs = new ConsumerArgs[numConsumer];
   pthread_t *consumerThreads = new pthread_t[numConsumer];
   for (int i = 0; i < numConsumer; i++)
   {
      ConsumerArgs *args = &(consumerArgs[i]);
      args->retailer = retailers[i];
      args->inventory = &inventory;
      assert(pthread_create(
                           &(consumerThreads[i]),
                           NULL,
                           consumer,
                           args
                           ) == 0);

   };
   for (int i=0; i < numConsumer; i++)
   {
      void *retVal;
      pthread_join(consumerThreads[i],&retVal);
      string report = *(string *)retVal;
      cout << report << endl;
   };
   // final report
   cout << "Maximum size of the inventory: "
        << inventory.getMax()
        << endl;
   // Remove arrays from heap.
   delete producerArgs;
   delete producerThreads;
   delete consumerArgs;
   delete consumerThreads;
   return 0;
}

/***********************************************************
 * PRODUCER
 * Create those cars.
 * This function is not currently thread safe. You will need
 * to introduce a critical section in such a way that we do
 * not compromise the queue nor produce two cars with the
 * same serial number.
 **********************************************************/
void *producer(void *args)
{
   ProducerArgs *producerArgs = (ProducerArgs *)args;
   int producerNumber = producerArgs->producerNumber;
   cout << "Producing car " << producerNumber << endl;
   const char *model = producerArgs->model;
   Inventory *inventory = producerArgs->inventory;
   static int serialNumberNext = producerArgs->beginningSerialNumber;

   // continue as long as we still need to produce cars in this run
   while (serialNumberNext <= producerArgs->endingSerialNumber)
   {
      // now that we decided to build a car, it takes some time
      usleep(rand() % 150000);
       // a car to be added to the inventory
      Car car;
      car.model = model;
      car.serialNumber = serialNumberNext;
      // add the car to our inventory if we still need to
      pthread_mutex_lock(&inventoryLock);
      inventory->makeCar(car);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&inventoryLock);
      serialNumberNext++;
   }
   // all done!
   productionComplete = true;
   assert(!inventory->empty());
   // Signal to the consumer threads that production of a car is complete.
   sem_post(&semaphore);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/***********************************************************
 * CONSUMER
 * Sell those cars.
 * This function is not currently thread safe. You will need
 * to introduce a critical section in such a way that we
 * do not compromise the queue nor sell the same car twice.
 **********************************************************/
void *consumer(void *args)
{
   sem_wait(&semaphore);
   bool inventoryEmpty;
  ConsumerArgs *consumerArgs = (ConsumerArgs *)args;
   const char *retailer = consumerArgs->retailer;
   Inventory *inventory = consumerArgs->inventory;
   // collect our sales history into one string
   stringstream sout;
   sout << retailer << ":\n";
   // continue while there are still customers floating around
   // do we have one to sell
   pthread_mutex_lock(&inventoryLock);
   inventoryEmpty = inventory->empty();
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&inventoryLock);
   assert(!inventoryEmpty);
   // it takes time to sell our car
   usleep(rand() % 150000);
   cout << "Selling car. " << endl;
   Car car = inventory->sellCar();
   assert ((car.model != NULL) && (car.model != ""));
   sout << car << endl;
   // done
   string * report = new string(sout.str());
   return (void *)report;
}

/*********************************************
 * GET NUMBER
 * Generic prompt function with error checking
 ********************************************/
int getNumber(const char * prompt, int max)
{
   int value = -1;
   assert(cin.good());       // better not already be in error mode
   assert(prompt != NULL);   // the prompt better be a valid c-string
   assert(max > 0);          // it better be possible for valid data to exist

   // continue prompting until we have valid data
   while (value <= 0 || value > max)
   {
      cout << prompt;
      cin  >> value;

      // if the user typed a non-integer value, reprompt.
      if (cin.fail())
      {
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore();
         cout << "Error: non-integer value specified\n";
      }

      // if the user typed a valid outside the range, reprompt
      else if (value <= 0 || value > max)
         cout << "Error: value must be between 1 and "
              << max
              << endl;
   }

   return value;
}
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of code. Please don't expect people here to read through and debug all of that. Please create a [mcve] / [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and post *that* instead. You may even find the solution while creating that minimal example; that happens quite frequently.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Right, sorry. I've been working on one as we speak.

Comment: How are you determining you have successfully added to the queue? It looks to me that nothing will ever get added - beginningSerialNumber is initialised to 1 and the end is initialised to 0. Judging from where these two are compared in the while loop nothing will ever get added?

Comment: @castro: beginningSerialNumber is just an identifier. It is not used to identify something in a collection.